# Executing T-SQL script with dynamic query that requests ActiveDirectory with various usernames

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

folks!

I'm trying to execute dynamic query that requests the ActiveDirectory folder via LDAP. The query is below:

```
DECLARE @TargetUser VARCHAR(100)
SET @TargetUser = 'apilinktester'

DECLARE @QueryStr VARCHAR(1000), @LDAPStr VARCHAR(100)
SET @LDAPStr = 'LDAP://OU=TechAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com'
SET @QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''SELECT * FROM ''''' + @LDAPStr + ''''' WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND sAMAccountName = ''''' + @TargetUser + ''''')'
PRINT @QueryStr
EXECUTE (@QueryStr)
```

My query does fails with the following errors:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, 'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://OU=TechAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com'' WHERE objectClass = ''User'' AND sAMAccountName = ''apilinktester'')
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://OU=TechAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com' WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND sAMAccountName = 'apilinktester')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://OU=TechAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com' WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND sAMAccountName = 'apilinktester')'.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TargetUser VARCHAR(100)
SET @TargetUser = 'apilinktester'

DECLARE @QueryStr VARCHAR(1000), @LDAPStr VARCHAR(100)
SET @LDAPStr = 'LDAP://OU=TechAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com'
SET @QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''SELECT * FROM ''''' 
  + @LDAPStr + ''''' WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND sAMAccountName = ''''' 
  + @TargetUser + ''''''')'
          --need add---^^
PRINT @QueryStr
EXECUTE (@QueryStr)
```